# Calculate Moving Average on Previous Calculated Moving Average (Snowflake)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a dataset that looks something like this. I wish to calculate a modified moving average (column Mod_MA) for sales column based on the following logic :
If there is no event, then ST Else Average last 4 dates.

| Date | Item | Event | ST | Mod_MA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-01 | ABC |  | 100 | 100 |
| 2022-10-02 | ABC |  | 110 | 110 |
| 2022-10-03 | ABC |  | 120 | 120 |
| 2022-10-04 | ABC |  | 130 | 130 |
| 2022-10-05 | ABC | EV1 | 140 | 115 |
| 2022-10-06 | ABC | EV1 | 150 | 119 |
| 2022-10-07 | ABC |  | 160 | 160 |
| 2022-10-08 | ABC |  | 170 | 170 |
| 2022-10-09 | ABC |  | 180 | 180 |
| 2022-10-10 | ABC | EV2 | 190 | 157 |
| 2022-10-11 | ABC | EV2 | 200 | 167 |
| 2022-10-12 | ABC | EV2 | 210 | 168 |
| 2022-10-01 | XYZ |  | 100 | 100 |
| 2022-10-02 | XYZ |  | 110 | 110 |
| 2022-10-03 | XYZ |  | 120 | 120 |
| 2022-10-04 | XYZ |  | 130 | 130 |
| 2022-10-05 | XYZ | EV3 | 140 | 115 |
| 2022-10-06 | XYZ | EV3 | 150 | 119 |
| 2022-10-07 | XYZ | EV3 | 160 | 121 |
| 2022-10-08 | XYZ |  | 170 | 170 |
| 2022-10-09 | XYZ |  | 180 | 180 |
| 2022-10-10 | XYZ | EV4 | 190 | 147 |
| 2022-10-11 | XYZ | EV4 | 200 | 155 |
| 2022-10-12 | XYZ |  | 210 | 210 |

Hopefully the image helps clarify what I am going for.
I have tried LAG & AVG OVER ORDER BY but since I dont have an exact number of iterations I need to run, these dont work.

[Calculation Formulae](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bggrC.png)

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you specify what should be returned if you have fewer than 4 previous rows and one of them has an Event?

Comment: There are 2 cases here:
1. Sc#1 : If the event was from 2022-10-02 - 2022-10-03 then Mod_MA for 2022-10-02 = 2022-10-01, for 2022-10-03 = AVG(2022-10-01, 2022-10-02). So essentially take whatever is available until we have 4 data points.
2. Sc#2 : If the event was 3 days long starting from 2022-10-01 - 2022-10-02, then Mod_MA for these 3 days (each) = ST for 2022-10-04.